# How can I get rid of spiders webs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've recently dug my quarry/mine down to a certain level where it has encountered a large mineshaft section and I am building a mine cart track through it to a nearby ravine and caves (because, hey, pre-made tunnels!) I've blocked off sections with fences so I don't get lost but there's still an annoying amount of spiders webs about. If I'm in the mine cart it would be fine but walking about and even nudging them slows me down.

I've tried axes, spades, pickaxes and even digging out holes above and pouring lava on them (which works, although has the significant self-immolation hazard, when I've been mining and am carrying a lot of coal/cobblestone/some diamonds I'd rather avoid).

I'm playing on peaceful (Vanilla MC, no mods) so I don't have to worry about the spiders themselves.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hit them with a **sword** and you'll be rid of them in no time!

It is also possible to use **shears** to cut through the web.

Comment: Ah - probably because I'm on peaceful I don't carry a sword. Better put some of that spare Iron to good use...

Comment: use stone.. the type of sword does not really matter when it comes to the webs.

Comment: I have a *lot* of spare iron - probably 5 or 6 stacks of 64. As lunbocks says beneath I could make some shears instead.

Comment: Note: Sword doesn't make it drop strings, shears do, but sword is faster.

Comment: @SF Swords drop string nowadays, but it takes 2 durability points from the sword.

Comment: An important point: a SWORD loses (double!) durability cutting through webs, SHEARS do not. Hence shears are the preferred option.

Comment: Another handy tip is to place water, as it will instantly destroy any cobwebs in the area

Answer (score 18):

You can mine cobwebs relatively quickly with Shears or a Sword (at double durability cost of course), which drops some string.

Also, as you have noticed, liquids like lava work, however I would recommend water over lava because it spreads faster, drains faster when you pick it up again, and, well, it won't kill you.